# How to overlay the correct way

Tags: ros, ros2, overlay

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say I want to overlay the rcl package.

Right now I have eloquent installed from deb packages.
So rcl lib is at `/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/librcl.so` .

Then I have an overlay workspace `overlay_ws`, where the rcl repo is checked out from source.
And a development workspace `dev_ws`.

I build `overlway_ws` first, then `dev_ws`.
And I source in this order:

1. `/opt/ros/eloquent/setup.sh`
2. `overlay_ws/local_setup.sh`
3. `dev_ws/local_setup.sh`

The sourcing happens in my `.bashrc`. So by opening a new terminal or calling an alias I can source the ros environment.

So first I source my environment, then build `overlay_ws`.
Then source the environment and build `dev_ws`.
Then source again, to have dev packages available.

But it always gets the installed lib (/opt/ros/..) linked and not the overlayed one.
If I remove the installed lib, it works. But that's not what I want.

Can someone hint me in the right direction?
Is this the way it should work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349955/how-to-overlay-the-correct-way/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2020-04-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-20**:
Could you clarify *when* you actually `source` any workspaces? Right now it's rather ambiguous whether you first build everything and only afterwards `source`, or whether you interleave those commands.

It would be important to know when you run which command.

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2020-04-20**:
Ok, updated my question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-20**:
If you start with overlays, I would suggest not to `source` anything in your `.bashrc` (at least initially). It will only confuse. Do it manually.

The correct order would be:

- `source /opt/ros/eloquent`
- build your `overlay_ws` (which is actually an *underlay* I would say)
- `source overlay_ws`
- build your `dev_ws`
- `source dev_ws`

To `source` a workspace (or install location) essentially *activates* it. If you don't do that in the correct order, package paths will not be resolved to the correct workspace.

Having written this, I recall there are currently some issues with overlaying and ROS 2 workspaces, but I can't find the details right now.

Perhaps @marguedas can add something here.

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2020-04-20**:
If the dev_ws was not build before, the `setup.bash` is non existant and I can't source it anyway, which leads me to the next question. Do I need to build dev_ws from a clean state? Is it possible that a previous build cached some cmake linking paths or so? Then sourcing the overlay wouldn' have an effect at all.

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2020-04-20**:
Now I removed the installed librcl.so as a test, tried to build dev_ws and it failed. So my custom rcl lib is not found although it's built.  Then I removed the build folder of the failing package, built again and now it find's my lib. Looks like I need to clean the `dev_ws` completely.

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-04-20**:
@gvdhoorn maybe you're referring to https://answers.ros.org/question/349612/ros2-osrf-docker-container-fails-to-build/ this was a temporary issue that has now been solved.

The suggested workflow of not sourcing automatically before building and building + sourcing moving up the workspace chain looks good :+1:
In my experience having dedicated (different) terminals for building and running code helps as wel

However what @madmax is trying to do is not a supported use case that I know of.
Building packages already installed from debs in overlay is discouraged. It may work but may break in subtle ways. You'd need to *at least* make sure to rebuild every dependent of RCL (rclcpp, rclpy and any branch up your dependency tree from rcl) in your overlay and they should be before the debs ones on your various paths (AMENT_PREFIX_PATH, CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PATH etc) .  Otherwise some libraries may still be pointing to the old rcl library.
This is most likely what's happening here

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2020-04-20**:
***Building packages already installed from debs in overlay is discouraged.*** -> this would be a good hint in the documentation. I do it like that because of the discussion [here.](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-logging/6469/34?u=maxlein) And I hoped it would be enough to just build rcl and spdlog package.  But after cleaning `dev_ws` and building again, it will always take the installed lib instead of the last sourced one.
I hoped the sourcing also does something like a library priorization, like on which path to look first for a library when building but that doesn't seem to be the case.
But after opening a new terminal, which resets all the PATH variables, and building `dev_ws` from there, the linking was correct.

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2020-04-20**:
Could you pls provide the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH after all your source operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So to sum it up:

I first cleaned my dev_ws and cleared the package and prefix path vars.
Then  sourced and build the underlay of dev_ws.
Source the underlay and build overlay.
Source overlay.

In my case I call a function which sources .bashrc and the workspaces in correct order.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=""                                                                                                                                                  
export AMENT_PREFIX_PATH=""                                                                                                                                                
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=""                                                                                                                                                
source ~/.bashrc
```

---

Originally posted by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) with karma: 496 on 2020-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0